# Mongo - Group documents with different regexes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have a collection called `vacancy` with those fields:

```js
[{
  "name": "Software Developer",
  "published_at": "2022-08-31"
},
{
  "name": "Tech Lead",
  "published_at": "2022-08-31"
},
{
  "name": "Team Lead",
  "published_at": "2022-08-31"
},
{
  "name": "Software Engineer",
  "published_at": "2022-08-31"
}]
```

What would be the aggregation query that would returns to me two groups based on two REGEXes which will verify a word existence in the field name.

Something like that:

```js
[{
  "_id": "Software",
  "count": 2
},
{
  "_id": "Lead",
  "count": 2
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query1

- group by `null` (all collection 1 group)
- create two custom groups
- to the first sum 1 if Software else 0
- to the second sum 1 if Lead else 0

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=630fc26b78a49d8782851490)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": null,
    "Software": 
     {"$sum": 
       {"$cond": 
         [{"$regexMatch": {"input": "$name", "regex": "Software"}}, 1, 0]}},
    "Lead": 
     {"$sum": 
       {"$cond": 
         [{"$regexMatch": {"input": "$name", "regex": "Lead"}}, 1, 0]}}}}])
```

If you want the exact same output like in your example try this, but maybe the first query is ok also.

Query2

- like the above, but root becomes array, that is unwinded
- and finaly replaces the root to get the 2 documents like in your expected output

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=630fc62478a49d8782851493) (you can put the mouse in the end of each stage to see what it does)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": null,
    "Software": 
     {"$sum": 
       {"$cond": 
         [{"$regexMatch": {"input": "$name", "regex": "Software"}}, 1, 0]}},
    "Lead": 
     {"$sum": 
       {"$cond": 
         [{"$regexMatch": {"input": "$name", "regex": "Lead"}}, 1, 0]}}}},
 {"$unset": ["_id"]},
 {"$project": {"array": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$unwind": "$array"}, {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$array"}},
 {"$project": {"_id": "$k", "count": "$v"}}])
```

Comment: It worked very well, thanks a lot!